# loading image from xml issue as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have created a Flash CC Professional file that loads XML data that includes links, multiple text sections and an image link.  as users progress though the program and text, the corresponding image should load into a mc named imgholder.  I have traced the var 'img' from the xml file to the incremental image loader but still can't figure out why the image isn't loading into the container.  ...oh and it isn't throwing any errors.

HELP!! thanks in advance!

Frame 1 AS3:

```
    var questions:Array=new Array();
var answers:Array=new Array();
var numb:Array=new Array();
var rtext:Array=new Array();
var img:Array = new Array();



//XML loader
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
loader.load(new URLRequest("UT_quiz.xml"));
function loadXML(e:Event):void
{
        var myxml = new XML(e.target.data);
        var loop =myxml.ques.length();
                for (var i=0;i<loop;i++){
                    questions[i]=myxml.ques[i].q1;
                    numb[i]=myxml.ques[i].qnum;
                    answers[i]=[myxml.ques[i].op1,myxml.ques[i].op2,myxml.ques[i].op3,myxml.ques[i].op4];
                    rtext[i]=myxml.ques[i].riddle;
                    img[i]=myxml.ques[i].image;


                }//loop
                gotoAndPlay(2);

}
stop();
```

Frame 2 AS3:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.events.Event;

var qno=0; var rnd1;

function change_question(){
                tick.visible=false;cross.visible=false;
                rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*4);
                q.text=questions[qno];
                qnum.text=numb[qno];
                rtxt.text=rtext[qno];
                imgholder.MovieClip=img[qno];
                if(rnd1==1){opt1.text=answers[qno][0];opt2.text=answers[qno][1];opt3.text=answers[qno][2];opt4.text=answers[qno][3];}
                if(rnd1==2){opt1.text=answers[qno][3];opt2.text=answers[qno][0];opt3.text=answers[qno][1];opt4.text=answers[qno][2];}
                if(rnd1==3){opt1.text=answers[qno][2];opt2.text=answers[qno][3];opt3.text=answers[qno][0];opt4.text=answers[qno][1];} 
                if(rnd1==4){opt1.text=answers[qno][1];opt2.text=answers[qno][2];opt3.text=answers[qno][3];opt4.text=answers[qno][0];}
                }//function change_question

function enable_disable(a){
    if(a==0){shade1.mouseEnabled=false;shade2.mouseEnabled=false;shade3.mouseEnabled=false;shade4.mouseEnabled=false;}
    if(a==1){shade1.mouseEnabled=true;shade2.mouseEnabled=true;shade3.mouseEnabled=true;shade4.mouseEnabled=true;}} 

change_question();


next_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction1);
function ButtonAction1(eventObject:MouseEvent) {

        qno++;change_question();

if(MovieClip(root).currentGalleryItem == 4){
            MovieClip(root).currentGalleryItem--;
            MovieClip(root).slideRight();
        }   
    }

shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2);
shade2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction3);
shade3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction4);
shade4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction5);

function ButtonAction2(eventObject:MouseEvent) {if(rnd1==1){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade1.y;tick.x=shade1.x; score+=50; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade1.y;cross.x=shade1.x; score-=25; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}}
function ButtonAction3(eventObject:MouseEvent) {if(rnd1==2){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade2.y;tick.x=shade2.x; score+=50; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade2.y;cross.x=shade2.x; score-=25; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}}
function ButtonAction4(eventObject:MouseEvent) {if(rnd1==3){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade3.y;tick.x=shade3.x; score+=50; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade3.y;cross.x=shade3.x; score-=25; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}}
function ButtonAction5(eventObject:MouseEvent) {if(rnd1==4){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade4.y;tick.x=shade4.x; score+=50; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade4.y;cross.x=shade4.x; score-=25; scorecounter.text = score.toString();}}



var score:Number = 0;

function init():void {
    if (score < 0) {
        score == 0;
    }
    scorecounter.text = score.toString();
}


/*var gameStartTime:uint;
var gameTime:uint;

function currTime(e:Event) {
    gameStartTime = getTimer();
    gameTime = 0;
}

addEventListener(event.ENTER_FRAME,showTime);

function showTime(e:Event) {
    gameTime = getTimer()-gameStartTime;
    gameTimeField.text = "Time: "+gameTime;
}*/

init();

stop();
```

Comment: XML stores text, not binary data, so whatever data is in `myxml.ques[i].image` should first be parsed and the image retrieved. I don't see how and what do you process from that field.

Comment: sorry, I guess this is extending beyond my expertise.  the .image from the xml stores the URL to the image I'm looking to display.  When the function change_question is fired, I'm wanting the corresponding image to display I just don't know where to go from there.  I can create a separate loader in XML but when I'm trying to bind it with the corresponding text I get lost.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, you've got an URL in your `image` field? You definitely need to load that image, but in order to know what question it relates to, you need to link the question number to the image. You can do that with a say `Dictionary` that would hold links from generated image loader objects to question numbers. An example:

```
public var ll:Dictionary=new Dictionary(); // place alongside other global arrays
// this will store our links
...
for (var i=0;i<loop;i++){
    questions[i]=myxml.ques[i].q1;
    numb[i]=myxml.ques[i].qnum;
    var imgsrc:String=myxml.ques[i].image; // img will hold images, and will be filled later
    var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImage);
    l.load(new URLRequest(imgsrc));
    ll[l]=i; // create a link
}//loop
...
function loadImage(e:Event):void {
    var l:URLLoader=e.target as URLLloader;
    if (!l) return; // safety check
    if (!ll[l]) return; // unfilled dictionary - BAD, should take measures if this triggers
    var num:int=ll[l]; // retrieve link
    img[num]=l; // fill the image
    l.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImage); // clean up
}
```

Whenever you decide to display an image, you'd better wait until it's loaded, say display "Loading, please wait" if the user clicks the quiz too fast, or plain wait for all the loaders to finish before even starting the quiz. Error handling is also required.